# Is ApproveAndCall also vulnerable to double withdrawal attack as is Approve?

Tags: solidity

As above, is ApproveAndCall also vulnerable to double withdrawal attack?

https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/6uckdx/reminder_about_problems_of_most_erc20_tokens/

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the code of the contract that `approveAndCall` calls.

If the function being called by `approveAndCall` always immediately uses `transferFrom` to transfer all the approved tokens, it is not vulnerable.

Otherwise it might be vulnerable, because the transaction could in effect be the same as a normal `approve` without the call to the approvee. The approvee would have a chance to inject a `transferFrom` in between two `approveAndCall` transactions. It all depends on the code of the called contract.